# Is there a case where a z-index can be overridden entierly in a file?

Tags: html, css

```js
function openNav(mName, mID) {
  console.log('In Open Nav');
  document.getElementById('myNav').style.height = '100%';
  menuItemOrderButton = document.getElementById('overlay-menuitem-order');
  menuItemOrderButton.onclick = addToOrder(mName, mID);
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('myNav').style.height = '0';
  console.log("Closing nav!");
}

function addToOrder(mName, mID) {
  console.log("IT WORKS!");
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -10 !important;
}

.overlay-menuitem {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 70% !important;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: #FFF;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -5 !important;
}

.overlay-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 18px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  font-size: 29px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 101;
}

.overlay-order-button {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  Background: #212326;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 100000 !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="openNav(1,2)"> Click me to open the overlay </button>
  <div>


    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content" onclick="closeNav()">
        <div class="overlay-menuitem" style="background:#FFF;">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="overlay-close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <div id="test" style="position: static;">
            <button id="overlay-menuitem-order" class="overlay-order-button">ORDER ONLINE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to create an overlay upon the click of a box. When this box is clicked, an overlay covers the screen showing a more detailed version of the box the user clicked. See Code snippet above to where the button shown in the overlay is not being clicked and not sending to addToOrder. I added a code snippet per the request of the commenters. The point I am not understanding is why the z-index attributes are not working, even with important tags.

Comment: I would highly suggest using an accessible modal script to ensure it meets baseline accessibility requirements. https://github.com/KittyGiraudel/a11y-dialog is a good one. These posts also have more info https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialog-modal/examples/dialog/ https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/making-modal-windows-better-for-everyone/

Comment: So I should reformat the HTML declarations to be a modal?

Comment: Pls provide your minimal javascript code. Also note that you have a typo with qote missing in the button after the onclick() function

Comment: Your HTML as posted is invalid with a missing double quote - perhaps a copy/paste error but just in case. BUT we cannot really tell without the related JavaScript code - perhaps create a working snippet in you question with the HTML, CSS and JavaScript to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Mehdi I added Javascript clarification

Comment: You still have a typo in your openNav() function should be menuItemOrderButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'addToOrder(' + mName + ',' + mID +')') maybe it helps if not a copy/paste error. Also if did not could you provide the minimal reproducible snippet

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss added a working snippet. Sorry for the delays.

Comment: And here I thought we were done with `javascript:` URLs.... Le sigh. That's almost always a sign you're using a link when what you want is a `<button>`...

Comment: I don't understand, I see the overlay covering the page, can you clarify what do you mean by "the z-index atributes are not working"? maybe add an image of what are you seeing vs what do you expect to see

Comment: @DanielCruz The button that says "Order Online" should be receiving a click and send to "addToOrder()". However, the click is being sent to the overlay-content, which it should not go to. The button has a z-index of 1000000, which is ludicrious, but I had to test, and the overlay-content has a z-index of -10. That is where I am confused on why the z-index attributes are not working.

Comment: Used the snippet code formatter to clarify view of invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code, and they are not related with z-index

**The first problem** is that you are passing `menuItemOrderButton.onclick` the result of a function call, not its declaration. You need to pass a function declaration. Otherwise what happens is that the function is called when the code runs, then the return value (in this case `undefined` because you are not returning anything) is saved as the `onclick` handler. In other words, what you are doing here is something like this: `menuItemOrderButton.onclick = undefined`

I know its confusing because when you define onclick inside HTML, you have to specify the code to be executed (the function call) but inside javascript, you have to put the declaration because the function call will be called immediately when the code is parsed, not when the event happens (as you expect)

That's why I strognly recommend you to be consistent. Declare your events always in your HTML or always in your javascript (most recommended the latter). That will also help you debug in the future as you will know all the events are registered in one place.

The second problem is that you are using `pointer-events:none;` on your modal. This property applies to the whole container, so the elements inside it will also stop listening to events. Maybe you did it with the intend of prevent the event from being capture by the container, but this is not necessary.

The following is the fixed code for your reference

```js
function openNav(mName, mID) {
    console.log('In Open Nav');
    document.getElementById('myNav').style.height = '100%';
    menuItemOrderButton = document.getElementById('overlay-menuitem-order');
    menuItemOrderButton.onclick = addToOrder(mName, mID);
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById('myNav').style.height = '0';
    console.log("Closing nav!");
}

function addToOrder(mName, mID){
  // return a function. This function will be called when the event is fired
  return function () {
    console.log("IT WORKS!");
    console.log({mName, mID}); // the closure will keep access to your variables even if it executes after
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    height: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.overlay-content {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -10 !important;
}

.overlay-menuitem {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%; 
    max-height: 70% !important;
    max-width: 400px; 
    border: 0px solid #000; 
    border-radius: 18px; 
    background:#FFF;
    /*pointer-events:none;*//*Don't use this on a div that contains the element you want to interact with*/
    z-index: -5 !important;
}

.overlay-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    float: right;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 18px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    font-size: 29px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 101;
}

.overlay-order-button {
  position: relative;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
     font-size:16px;
     Background: #212326;
     background-size:contain;
     width:200px;
     height:45px;
     border:none;
     cursor:pointer; 
     margin-top:12px;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     color: #FFF;
     font-weight: 500;
     letter-spacing:.5px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     z-index: 100000 !important;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="openNav(1,2)"> Click me to open the overlay </button>
<div>


<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content" onclick="closeNav()">
    <div class="overlay-menuitem" style="background:#FFF;">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="overlay-close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <div id="test" style="position: static;">
      <button id="overlay-menuitem-order"   class="overlay-order-button">ORDER ONLINE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much. This instantly solved the problem. I've never felt happier to see a coding problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understanding the issue you described, but I assume you have an issue with the event bubbling. Check out Event Bubbling topic (e.g. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/event-bubbling-in-javascript/#how-to-stop-event-bubbling).

Also, you have a typo in your code `onclick="addToOrder(menuItem)>` - you are missing closing `"` after the function.

I would also suggest a different structure of the HTML in the first place. To me, it seems you can either remove one level of nesting or at least separate elements. One more thing, check of the `dialog` element in HTML (it might be useful for your case).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful article! However, the event bubbling does not seem to be what is happening, since "overlay-content" is overriding all click elements.

Also, thank you for pointing out the typo. It is fixed!

I have never heard of dialogue boxes, I can try that out.